# Create backup database without sdcard

Tags: android, database, backup

I'd like to create a backup of my database, but I don't have SDCARD on my phone. I'd like to create the backup in the internal storage, but the next code fail...

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//storage//sdcard0//MyApp//turnos.db";
            String backupDBPath = "turnos.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
           }
        } mensajeOK("INFO", "Copia creada.");                       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: In the latest Android Studio and using Java 1.8, you get the following compiler error for the close statements: `Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed`. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
String currentDBPath = "//storage//sdcard0//MyApp//turnos.db";
```

is probably giving you most of your problems.

1. You say you don't have an SD Card, and yet are trying to read the file from the SD Card. This will likely result in a FileNotFoundException.
2. File paths don't usually contain `//`. It is always `/`
3. Even if your SD Card is present, it may not be following this path. **Always** use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get to the SD Card

Answer (score 5):

1. **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**.
2. `//` is not the directory separator. `/` is.
3. `/storage/sdcard0` may not exist -- use the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, or `getExternalFilesDir()`
4. `getDataDirectory()` is unlikely to be a relevant location
5. Your existing database, if you put it in the normal spot, can be found via `getDatabasePath()`, a method available on `Context` (e.g., your `Activity`)
6. **ALWAYS LOG YOUR STACK TRACES WITH EXCEPTIONS**, such as via `Log.e()`, rather than throwing away that information, to help you better debug matters

That may not be all the problems with your current approach, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! With your help, I have done the backup of my database:

```
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "data/com.turnos/databases/Horarios";
            String backupDBPath = "BackupHorarios"; 
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```